# in Rust, why can FnOnce mutate values?

Tags: rust, closures

I've always seen `FnOnce` as a function that can consume value in its scope, but not mutate, that would be `FnMut` and you would need a `mut` closure to do things like that.

Yet, [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=303e896ab4f1925c5ba0768bc239bf0a) seems to work:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Debug, Clone)]
struct Thing(u8);

fn thing<T>(closure: T) -> Result<Thing, ()> where T: FnOnce() -> Result<Thing, ()> {
    closure()
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = None;
    let b = || {
        a = Some(Thing(8));
        a.ok_or_else(|| panic!("yo"))
    };
    let c = thing(b).unwrap();
    println!("{a:?}");
    println!("{c:?}");
}
```

and prints:

```
Some(Thing(8))
Thing(8)
```

Effectively, the non-mut closure can mutate mutable variable in its environment if it's cast to an FnOnce and used only once. Why isn't Rust enforcing an FnMut and a mutable closure here? I'm confused.

Comment: You are mistaken, a `FnOnce` can do anything a `FnMut` can do while also being able to *move out* of its captured environment.

Comment: Then why doesn’t it require the closure to be mut, like FnMut does?

Comment: It may be instructive to remove `Copy` from `Thing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't Rust enforcing an FnMut and a mutable closure here?

There are two parts to this question:

1. why isn't an `FnMut` bound required, though we're clearly mutating a captured value?
2. why **doesn't** Rust require `capture: T` to be `mut capture: T`, and `b` to be `mut b`?

The answer to both question is the same, and boils down to: because we're not mutating those variables, we're passing ownership. (The first revision of this answer was actually confused about the answer to the first question, stating that every `FnOnce` value is automatically `FnMut`, which is untrue - it's actually the other way around, it's `FnMut` that implies `FnOnce`.)

Starting from `b`, `thing(b)` doesn't mutate `b`, it *passes ownership* of `b` to `thing()`, and that doesn't require `mut` regardless of whether `thing()` will end up mutating the value (which the caller can't even know). Likewise, invoking `()` on an `FnOnce` closure doesn't mutate `capture`, it *passes ownership* of `capture` to the `()` operator of `FnOnce`, which [takes self by value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#tymethod.call_once).

Consider a simpler example that does the same thing:

```
// we mutate `v` even though it's not mut
fn mutate_owned(v: Vec<u32>) {
    let mut foo = v;
    foo.push(42);
    println!("{foo:?}")
}

fn main() {
    // we'll end up mutating `b` even though it's not mut
    let b = vec![1, 2, 3];
    mutate_owned(b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The phrasing "consume captured variables" in the docs is a little unfortunate, in my opinion. Think of it like this: A `Fn` can borrow its environment; a `FnMut` can borrow its environment *mutably*; and a `FnOnce` can take ownership of its environment. And in Rust, if you own a value, you're allowed to mutate it. They are subtypes of one another. A `FnMut` can do anything a `Fn` can do *and more*; a `FnOnce` can do anything a `FnMut` can do *and more*.

Comment: Then why doesn’t FnOnce require the closure to be mut like FnMut does?

Comment: Because `thing` takes ownership of `b`.

Comment: And calling a `FnOnce` closure takes `self` by value. Calling a `FnMut` closure takes `&mut self` which is why the binding needs to be mutable.

Comment: @David天宇Wong FnOnce doesn't need `mut` for the same reason moving out of a variable does not need `mut`.

Comment: The first part of my answer (claiming that `FnOnce` implies `FnMut`) was inaccurate, I've edited it to provide a better explanation.